# Android Widget onClick not working - Service won't start

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-service, android-broadcast

**Update: Solved it, solution below**

I'm trying to write a widget that starts a service, which then will do some stuff not implemented yet. So far my service is only that:

```
public class SmartWifiService extends Service {

private static final String WIDGET_CLICK = "de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget.WIDGET_CLICK";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.e("DEBUG", "Service started");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Widget clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    stopSelf();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

So everything it does is send a Toast and stop itself after that.

Unfortunately, it doesn't come to that. My Provider looks like that:

```
public class SmartWifiWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "onUpdate called");
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, SmartWifiWidgetProvider.class);
    clickIntent.setAction("de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget.WIDGET_CLICK");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(),
            0, clickIntent, 0);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout, pendingIntent);
    //for (int ID:appWidgetIds) {
    //    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(ID, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
    //}
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "received");
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if(intent.getAction().equals("de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget.WIDGET_CLICK")){
        Log.e("DEBUG", "Click action fits");
        Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SmartWifiService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
}
```

I went through several answered questions here, changed stuff, added stuff, and so far nothing really worked, and I still have no idea why.

When I click the Widget there is no animation, but I'm pretty sure my widget itself is clickable:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/layout"
          android:clickable="true">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/wifi"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="+id/widgetImage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also tried it with ImageButton, no change in effect.

I hope you guys can help me, I have been sitting in this little thing for days and my head is spinning (not literally).

Greetings,

Marlon

Edit: Here's my Manifest:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/wifi"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".SmartWifiWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            <action android:name="de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget.WIDGET_CLICK"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   android:resource="@xml/smart_wifi_widget_info"/>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget.SmartWifiService"/>

</application>
```

Edit 2: Update; updated to current state of my code, adapted to Y.S.' answer.

LogCat after adding the widget, clicking it still doesn't do anything:

```
04-08 20:12:30.985  14867-14867/de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget E/DEBUG﹕ received
04-08 20:12:30.998  14867-14867/de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget E/DEBUG﹕ received
04-08 20:12:30.998  14867-14867/de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget E/DEBUG﹕ onUpdate called
04-08 20:12:31.155  14867-14867/de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget E/DEBUG﹕ received
```

**Solution:**

The blowing line was `views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetImage, pendingIntent);`, I had R.id.layout instead of widgetImage there. It seems a widget doesnt hand the click through to views below if it doesnt get handled.

Comment: have you seen my answer ?

Comment: Yes I have, was eating and then needed some time to try it ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Problem:**

To start a `Service` in this way, you need to use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, not `PendingIntent.getService()`. And the `WIDGET_CLICK` action needs to be specified in the app manifest under the `receiver` tag, not the `service` tag.

**STEP 1:**

Replace

```
Intent clickIntent = new Intent("de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget.WIDGET_CLICK");
```

with

```
Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, SmartWifiWidgetProvider.class);
clickIntent.setAction("de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget.WIDGET_CLICK");
```

**STEP 2:**

Replace

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context.getApplicationContext(),
        0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

with

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(),
        0, clickIntent, 0);
```

**STEP 3:**

In the manifest, add the *action* to the `receiver` tag and remove it from the `service` tag:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/wifi"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name=".SmartWifiWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            <action android:name="de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget.WIDGET_CLICK"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   android:resource="@xml/smart_wifi_widget_info"/>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget.SmartWifiService"></service>

</application>
```

**STEP 4:**

Set the `PendingIntent` on the `RemoteViews` in your widget:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetImage, pendingIntent);
```

**STEP 5:**

Override the `onReceive()` method of the `SmartWifiWidgetProvider` class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals("de.regenhardt.smartwifiwidget.WIDGET_CLICK")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SmartWifiService.class)
        startService(i);
    }
}
```

Try this. This should start the `Service` correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, hoped I would would get something like this :)

Unfortunately it doesn't work so far, but I also had to make some changes:

`R.id.layout` is the ID of my LinearLayout surrounding the ImageView, I hope I deducted that right.

startService wouldn't be recognized, so I made it context.startService.

Instead of the for loop in the end, I got `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);`

Comment: We are making a small mistake or two somewhere ... keep looking for it, and let me know. This isn't rocket science, just a simple logical mistake somewhere ... :)

Comment: I put log commands everywhere, maybe it helps to see something, updated my question ^^

Comment: yes i noticed that you updated the question yesterday ... hmm, am unable to guess why its still not working :/

Comment: I GOT IT

Was indeed one little word: the the `setOnClickPendingIntent`I had to put it on the R.id.widgetImage, not the R.id.layout. It seems the tap didn't fall through the ImageView inside the LinearLayout o.O

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt: ok great ... so its working now ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your service into manifest:

```
<service android:name="SmartWifiService"></service>
```

You didn't say how you are calling service, so I could say that need to call startService(Intent) from some Activity - it would not start without that.

Comment: Added my Manifest, Service was already there.
I thought the `views.setOnClickPendingIntent(ID, pendingIntent);` would make my widget start the service each time i click on it?

Comment: I didn't see in your code some Intent for launch service. It should look like new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SmartWifiService.class).

Comment: I had that before reading and trying those other answers, but it didn't work either. Tried it again to be sure, added it to my question.